# Display Name=Value of all environment variables in C++

Tags: c++

Newbie question:

I want to print the name and value of every environment variable of my process to stdout. The following example prints the value of every environment variable but not the name. How can I additionally print the name ?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp) {
  char** env;
  for (env = envp; *env != 0; env++) {
    cout << *env << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This will depend on your OS & possibly compiler.

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing the name?  Usually (for every compiler/os combination I've used) it'd be of the form <name>=<value>

Comment: Agreed.  For example, I just compiled your program with g++ under Ubuntu and it prints out stuff like `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: The man pages for `getenv(3)` and `setenv(3)` are generally helpful for such tasks

Comment: My primary target is a POSIX-ish system with gcc. It doesn't hurt if it works on windows too.

Comment: right, this is a stupid question, i should go to bed. close pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case this doesn't get closed and people wind up here.  Usually, each value pointed to by *envp  would be a string of the form:

```
<EnvironmentVariableName>=<EnvironmentValue>
```

Such as (taken from ideone.com):

```
TMPDIR=/home/Cat5sW
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/Cat5sW
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=0
HOME=/home/Cat5sW
```

You would then need to split the string, based on the '=' char.

As John has pointed out above, this may differ for some os/compiler combinations (although I've never encountered them).

Comment: When tired, some elements may fade in and out of existance (I'm sure we've all been there)